# C Language Multiply Program wont work properly

Tags: c, string, binary, multiplication

My program gets a binary string ( up to 200 characters long) and then it multiplies it by a decimal number. The calculator works only for the first 2-3 iterations. After that it doesn't return the correct result. Any help ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myfun.c"
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
int l,l1;
    char a[200],b[200],f[200];
int c[200],d[200];
    for (i=0;i<200;i++)
        {
        c[i]=0;
        d[i]=0;
        }
gets(a);

l=strlen(a);
l1=strlen(a);

for (int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        c[200-l+i]=a[i]-48;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////
for (int i=0;i<l1;i++)
    {
        d[200-l1+i]=a[i]-48;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////
    for (int t=1;t<193;t++) //here is specify how many times i am multypling

      bin_add(c,d);
      for (i=0;i<200;i++){
        printf("%d",c[i]);

      }
    return 0;
}
int bin_add(int c[200],int d[200])
{

   int car[200]; //carry
      i=200;
      car[i]=0;
      while (i >= 0) {
              //find carry and shift it left
              //find the sum
              car[i-1] = c[i] & (d[i] |car[i]) ;
              c[i]=(c[i]^d[i]) ^ car[i];
              i--;

      }
      return c[i];
      c[i]=0;
}
```

Comment: car[i] writes past the array since i=200, should make it i=199.  other than that i dont see anything obvious from a quick read of your source

Comment: wow, you like writing `200` a lot !

Comment: A hundred and ninety-three? Are you _sure_?

Comment: @TimRandall that meants 193 times the input

Comment: What are the contents of this file: `#include "myfun.c"`

Comment: regarding: `gets(a);`  the `gets()` function has been depreciated for years and completely removed from the latest C standard.  Your compiler should have told you this.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note other compilers use different options to produce the same thing.  Suggest using: `fgets()`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) use the character value (for instance '0') rather than the numeric value.  2) the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis I.E. 200.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: strongly suggest you obtain/download/install one of the `bignum` header files and associated library

Comment: regarding: `i=200;
      car[i]=0;`  regarding this kind of statement: `car[i-1] = c[i] & (d[i] |car[i]) ;`  in C, the index into an array has the range 0...(number of elements in array -1)  so the `car....` line is accessing beyond the end of the array `car[]`  resulting in undefined behavior